# How to save grayscale image in Pytorch?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, pytorch

I want to save grayscale image in Pytorch, each image has four gray values, `0`, `60`, `120` and `180`. I try the following way to save images, but the saved image is not I expected.

```
for i, (inputs) in enumerate(test_generator):
    pred = modelPl(inputs.float()).detach()
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (5,5))
    ax.imshow(pred[0,:,:], cmap = "gray")
    print(pred.shape)
    torchvision.utils.save_image(pred, saveTestPath + 'img_{0}.png'.format(i))
```

`Output:`
`torch.Size([400, 400])`

`Expected image:`

[image]

However, the saved picture is not correct as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that `torchvision.utils.save_image` requires values to be in range 0 to 1. Your images have values which are greater than 1 and hence the problem.

You can check this by dividing the tensor by `255` (or some appropriate number). You can also try to set `normalize=True` and see if it can automatically normalize the data for you.

Comment: Thanks, I solve the problem by dividing the tensor by `255`.